# Can the continuity correction when modelling non-integer values in discrete data be something other than .5?

Tags: normal-distribution

My question is about using a continuity correction on a set of discrete data that is not binomial. For example, a data set containing the total amount spent (dollars and cents) at the grocery store for 100 customers. Values range from $95.73 to $123.11 say. Obviously, there is a mean and SD for the amount spent, so let’s assume the distribution is roughly normal. Since this data is discrete (there are “gaps” between each possible consecutive values like $98.67 and $98.68), should we use a continuity correction when making a prediction such as what is the probability a shopper will spend more than $100? If so, is the correction still .5 considering the values in the data are not whole numbers and .5 does not split the gap? I am wondering if the correction in this case should be .005?